# AWS SQS - Access Policy - to restrict resources sending messages to SQS based on aws:SourceArn is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs

I want to allow only ONE lambda (`arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:444455556666:function:source-lambda`) function to send messages to my SQS queue (`arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:444455556666:target-sqs`). So I attached the below Access Policy to my SQS queue. However, this policy is not allowing the specified Lambda to send messages to the SQS queue, and returning `AccessDenied` exception.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "Policy1666948352567",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1666948347116",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:444455556666:target-sqs",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnNotEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:444455556666:function:source-lambda"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

Policy rules follow, this Priority

```
Explicit Deny ( Highest ) --> Explicit Allow --> Implicit Deny ( Default )
```

Here in your policy, you have defined explicit denied for all other resources which are not `arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:444455556666:function:source-lambda`

But you haven't explicitly allowed the lambda to send a message to that SQS, so Implicit deny applied and hence you are receiving `Access Denied`

---

**Solution :**

Why don't you use `"Effect": "Allow",` and `"ArnEquals":`, this will satisfy your use case by only allowing that specific lambda to send a message.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "Policy1666948352567",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1666948347116",
      "Effect": "Allow", // <---- HERE
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:444455556666:target-sqs",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": { // <--- HERE
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:444455556666:function:source-lambda"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But, the policy you provided is not respecting the `SourceArn`. It is allowing any Lambda to SendMessage to the SQS.

Comment: That might be possible if you have attached role/some policies with all Lambda, which is allowing them to send messages to any SQS.

Comment: @MadhavaReddy , and have you tried passing specific lambda arn in principal, instead of *, in my solution?

"Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:444455556666:function:source-lambda"
      },

Comment: https://corpoprogrammer.pl/sqs-access-policy-which-denies-receiving-messages-except-one-lambda/

Vivek - Can you please see the above article (though this is failing in some cases)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement similar restrictions using the following SQS Access policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT-NUMBER>:root"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "<QUEUE-ARN>",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:userid": "*<LAMBDA-FUNCTION-NAME>*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It may not be the best way to implement this restriction, but at least it works.